# How to make a slider on body with interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

This body slider dosent work.
Can any help? i got it working on a image, but not the body.
This is the code that is a problem with

```
var slides = new Array();
slides[0] = 'images/0.jpg';
slides[1] = 'images/1.jpg';
slides[2] = 'images/2.jpg';
var currentSlide = 0;

function slideshow() {
currentSlide++;
if(currentSlide >= slides.length)
{
currentSlide = 0;
}
var bla = slides[currentSlide];

$(body).css("background-image", bla.attr("src"));
}
setInterval('slideshow();', 1000);
```

Comment: This Code: $(body).css("background-image", bla.attr("src"));

Comment: Try `$('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ bla +')')`

Comment: HAHA Just did the right same thing before you posted and it worked:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bla` is not a jQuery object so it doesn't have `attr` method. In CSS you'd write `background-image: url(img.jpg)`, so you have to do the same in JavaScript.

Then `$(body)` won't work, you need a selector like `$('body')`, or `$(document.body)`

Try this:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ bla +')');
```

Also is worth pointing out that you should pass a reference to the function in `setInterval` and not a string as it triggers `eval` and you don't want that:

```
setInterval(slideshow, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this :

```
function slideshow() {
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide >= slides.length){
        currentSlide = 0;
    }
    var bla = slides[currentSlide];


    $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ bla +')');
}
```